# Does imap support multiple connections?

Tags: imap

I have a question: is it possible to have multiple connections to IMAP?

For example, one from outlook and one from roundcube, at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it’s possible. But it depend of the host.

For example gmail allow 15 simultaneous connections by IMAP.